# Recruited as a director, but I won't be a director straight away, was I misled?

Tags: job-offer, title, contract-extension

Bit of a tricky one, but I am in the midst of a move from a prestigious outfit in my field to a bit more of a niche outfit (promise of better work/life balance, and the pay is still good).

One of the reasons I was tempted out was because I was promised a senior management role, in addition to the financial benefits (my employment contract specifies the role as "Managing Director of XXXXX").

This was important to me as I am relatively young (not yet 30) and it was a relatively punchy jump up the corporate ladder (and so set me up for further advancement in 5 years or so).

However two days before leaving my current shop I get a phone call where the big boss tells me HR has cocked up and the incumbent MD has not been sacked yet. Therefore when I first land I have to initially report in at a more junior level (on same pay and benefits I negotiated) and not let on that I will be becoming MD following the incumbent being sacked for gross misconduct in the next few weeks.

Just seems a bit off to me, as I can understand the reasoning (there are a few deadlines they want to hit before xmas and don't want the disruption of sacking the current boss) but this messy situation wasn't made clear to me before I put my notice in my current job.

I have assurances I will be in role with title by the new year, but it does make me feel that my situation is more precarious than it should be.  Is it worth putting down in writing that I only accept the diminished title and role on a short term basis and if I am not in the role originally offered to me by the date they promised I will re-evaluate my position?

I may have to return the sign-on bonus at that point (unless I can get out of the claw-back somehow), but still my old shop has told me they will take me back if things dont work out.

Comment: Sounds like a personal choice you will have to make.  We won't be able to make that decision for you.  I personally would fight for the title, even if they have to add the word "Interim" to it, seems strange to keep a boss around that is being fired for gross misconduct though.

Comment: Point is the current MD doesnt know they are dead person walking apparently, so I will have to work with them for a few weeks and not let on that they brought me in to take their chair.

Comment: If they just verbally agreed, that's easy for them to conveniently forget about later. Get it in writing or it didn't happen.

Comment: There's no need to put your reservation in writing. You can *always* reevaluate your decision to join.

Comment: Guess from a contractual perspective, if I don't make clear I am not happy with the changed title it could be seen as an affirmation by conduct. At the moment I am fairly certain they have breached my contract which offers me a little legal protection at least.

Comment: I'd almost be tempted to say "Call me when the MD is gone, or pay me more $$ to cover the stress of keeping the big secret"

Comment: Bit late - my notice period from my current job expires tomorrow which is they shittyness of them communicating this through me two days before I am due to start.

Comment: @BobbyRoberts - As I pointed out, if the title is important, push back on getting the interim title. I assume you are prepared to walk away from the position?  If you agree upon the position without the title, have them put it in writing, when you will receive the title.  The alternative to them accepting your terms at this point, is they are left with somebody, who they plan to fire for gross misconduct.  I assume you fought for an iron clad contract?

Comment: Yeah, my other half is a lawyer so she looked over it and said it was fine and fairly standard. I think I will make clear when I land that I need a written assurance that my title is secure. Then if it doesn't materialize when they say it should I will find a new job in the background and terminate for breach. At the moment they are in breach of my contract unless I agree to the change of title.

Comment: Get it (the job level / salary) in writing, and make sure it has an acceptable deadline.

Comment: Have you considered asking them to push your start date until the current director has been properly relieved?  That seems to be the appropriate response here if the company does not want to advise the current director of the need to transition responsibilities to you.  I personally would consider trying to get out of this agreement.  **If they will do that to this director they will do that to the next director**

Comment: Sounds like you've been treated exceptionally well. Given a job offer of good pay and title beyond what you currently have, and the boss has the mindset to contact you before you start to share internal information. I would send that person a thank you letter for everything they've done for you so far, and try to stay positive. You have a new future ahead of you.

Comment: Also what would such a threat of "reevaluating" your position serve you, at this point? It will just alianate BigBoss. You can reevaluate anytime anyways - especially in probation...

Answer (score 4):

> Is it worth putting down in writing that I only accept the diminished
>   title and role on a short term basis and if I am not in the role
>   originally offered to me by the date they promised I will re-evaluate
>   my position?

I don't think you were misled, but make sure any promises your expecting to have the new employer keep **are in writing**, as part of your offer letter, including the change in title within a certain period of time.

Otherwise you have no assurances that any promises will be kept, and in your situation IMHO the title is a big deal.  While getting the agreed upon salary is important, its *equally important in your case to get the title too*.

Comment: Agreed - its weird because in my contract I have the title. They have the right to vary my role with my agreement, but there is no way I would accept demotion even if it is on the same benefits (as I would be hitting/exceeding those benefits at my old shop in short order, so the title is the path to progression here). I think I might get it down in email that I am not affirming the change in role. Also, arent they asking for a constructive dismissal claim here from the incumbent if they hire me and have me steal their functions before they sack them?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it worth putting down in writing that I only accept the diminished
>   title and role on a short term basis and if I am not in the role
>   originally offered to me by the date they promised I will re-evaluate
>   my position?

If it would make you feel better, then go ahead and write it down. But realistically, it's wasted effort.

You won't know what kind of messy situation you are really getting into until you are in place for a while. At that point it will either be a good situation for you or a bad situation. And at that point you can decide to stay or leave.

Writing that "I will re-evaluate my position" does nothing - other than perhaps antagonize your employer unnecessarily. You can re-evaluate at any time, for any reason.

> was I misled?

"Misled" implies intent. And you are in the only position to judge what they intended to do here. It would be very odd if they intended to trick you into joining the company - I don't see what the point would be in that.

If you truly believe they were being deceptive, then that's a very bad sign for your future at the company. And in that case, you may wish to consider backing out immediately.

On the other hand, if you believe that they fully intend to put you in the role you desire, but just had some squishiness with getting rid of your predecessor, then it would probably make sense to stick around and see how it plays out.

I've personally seen cases where HR intervened to slow down an inevitable process. Perhaps the big boss failed to fully discuss the plans with HR before offering you the terms of the position. It happens.

Comment: Would lose the breach of contract claim however if I accept the change via conduct however? That might impact the effectiveness of the claw-back provisions regarding my sign-on bonus (definitely have to repay if I terminate via notice, but suspect of employer has done a repudiatory breach of the terms of my employment I wouldn't have to).